# Meaning of stacked arrows

Tags: functions, notation, computability

I just stumbled across ([pag 5](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~amp66/documents/CCC2013.pdf)) a symbol made of two arrows stacked together (`\rightrightarrow` in latex, it seems that MathJax does not recognize it).

The author uses it without giving a definition, so I guess it is supposed to be quite standard/well-known in the field but I never met it. May someone point me to the definition?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I haven't seen these in this context before but the stacked arrow notation also occurs in Homological algebra, in exact sequences,  sometimes three or four arrows on top of each other and I have been at a loss to find a definition.

Comment: I have seen it used for "uniform convergence" but that is not the case here.

Comment: `\rightrightarrows`

Comment: The link is down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See : Klaus Weihrauch, [Computable Analysis : An Introduction](https://books.google.it/books?id=Ir6qCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA11) (2000), page 11:

> Usually we will denote a correspondence $f$ from $A$ to $B$ by $f : \subseteq A \rightrightarrows B$. A *partial function* $f : \subseteq A  \rightarrow B$ from $A$ to $B$ is a multi-valued fucntion $f : \subseteq A \rightrightarrows B$ such that the set $f[ \{ a \} ]$ contains only one element for each $a \in \text{dom}(f)$ .